# Delay in FCM “Firebase” and sometimes working without any delay

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I found bug in FCM. Notification is delayed for hours or minutes and sometimes without any delay without changing in code or internet speed or something else so I can't understand what is happening. There is SS show my console of functions in firebase https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBvd.jpg

```
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Noti/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context) =>
{
    const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


    console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);


    if (!data.after.val()) 
    {
        console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
        return null;
    }

    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/userstoken/${receiver_user_id}/token`).once('value');

    return DeviceToken.then(result => 
    {
        const token_id = result.val();

        const payload = 
        {
            notification:
            {
                title: "New ",
                body: `you have a new Chat Request, Please Check.`,
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
        .then(response => 
            {
                console.log('This was a notification feature.');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you didn't change anything about the code to change the behavior, then it's unlikely that anyone here can do anything about it. You might want to have a look at [Understanding message delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery) to see if it helps you understand the delivery behavior you're seeing.

Comment: i found something from minutes

Comment: the problem with token

Comment: so could you tell me how i can generate right token

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register?